# Installing RMagick Error on windows 7 to create image with Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rmagick

I want to install ImageMagick. I'm using windows 7 because I want to create an image with Ruby but, when I used the command `gem install rmagick` while using the Git Bash screen command, I got this error

```
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
checking for Ruby version >= 1.8.5... yes
checking for stdint.h... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/ruby
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:381:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
    from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:506:in `try_cpp'
    from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:931:in `block in have_header'
    from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:790:in `block in checking_for'
    from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:284:in `block (2 levels) in postpone'
    from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:254:in `open'
    from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:284:in `block in postpone'
    from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:254:in `open'
    from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:280:in `postpone'
    from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:789:in `checking_for'
    from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:930:in `have_header'
    from extconf.rb:194:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 0):

Install dev-kit for windows c c++ extensions http://rubyinstaller.org/add-ons/devkit/

Comment: sure , I'm installed DevKit on my path c:/DevKit & installed ImageMagick-6.8.8-Q8 on my path c:/ImageMagick-6.8.8-Q8

Comment: the error is suggesting that devkit is not found. Check your path variable and start a new terminal and try.

Comment: DevKit is installed on my pc on the path c:/DevKit

Answer (score 0):

Guy 
finaly i got the true method to install it on windows 7

1- install ImageMagick-6.7.9-0-Q16-windows-static.exe  in the path C:/ImageMagic 
2- install ImageMagick-6.7.9-0-Q16-windows-dll.exe  in the path C:/ImageMagic  
3- Extract the ImageMagick-6.8.8-2.tar in folder and rename it to SourceCode then set it in the path C:/ImageMagic/SourceCode
4- install mingw-get-setup.exe in the path C:/MinGW 
5- define the Environment Variables  for the user 
PATH - C:\MinGW\bin;

6- used the command (gem install rmagick -- '--with-opt-dir="C:/ImageMagick"')
7 - open Gemfile and set (gem 'rmagick')
8 - type the command (bundle-install)

you can follow this article 
 
https://github.com/rmagick/rmagick/wiki

the error happen to me because i was installed the ImageMagick  version 6.8